# Operations in Combination Expressions

Tags: python

I am new to programming and just learning about integers and point float numbers. How would expressions that contain both an integer and a point float be evaluated? Is it possible in an operation to have a combination of point float numbers and integers? ex: Can you divide an integer by a float?

Comment: In Python the division automatically converts the integer to a float.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, note that integers, floats, and operations are implemented differently between Python 2 and 3, and Python 3 is generally more intuitive. I know much less about 2 so I'll just cover 3.

> How would expressions that contain both an integer and a float be evaluated?

It depends on the expression. For example addition will produce a float; xor will produce an exception.

```
>>> 1.5 + 1
2.5
>>> 1 ^ 1.5
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for ^: 'int' and 'float'
```

And of course, if you call the `float` or `int` types, you will get that type out. E.g.

```
>>> int(1.5)
1
>>> float(1)
1.0
```

> Is it possible in an operation to have a combination of floats and integers? ex: Can you divide an integer by a float?

Try it! The worst that can happen is an exception!

```
>>> 5 / 2.5
2.0
```

So yes!